# Pass Method/Function as Argument and Invoke

Tags: php, slim

How can I pass a method as an argument to a function so it can be invoked from the function?

I'm trying to pass the Slim Framework's `redirect()` method from a route handler to an object method that handles the redirect logic:

```
$app->get('/contact', function() use ($app) {
  $obj = new Obj;
  $obj->handle_request($app->redirect);
});
```

And then in the object method:

```
public function handle_request(callable $redirect) {
  $redirect('/about');
}
```

That gives me this error: `Argument 1 passed to Obj::handle_request() must be callable, null given`

If I do the same thing without the `callable` type hint, I get this error: `Function name must be a string`

Comment: Better question is why are you passing the method when you can just pass the object and call the method?  The error is that you are accessing a property, which is null, and not a callable.  Essentially, $obj->prop is not a reference to a method of $obj but a property that $obj may or may not have.  Chances are they are using magic __set() somewhere in the object inheritance chain

Answer (score 2):

You are using the callable hint incorrectly. As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string.
>
> ...
>
> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

So in your case, you need to pass it as `array($app, 'redirect')`:

```
$app->get('/contact', function() use ($app) {
    $obj = new Obj;
    $obj->handle_request(array($app, 'redirect'));
});
```

However in your case, as other answers have stated, unless you are doing more than just calling `redirect` in `handle_request` or have a particular requirement to pass a callback in this way, you are probably better off just passing `$app` to `handle_request` and letting that do what it needs with `$app` itself. This is a better OO pattern.

Comment: Sorry but this code is, well not good.  Why recreate an obj, that is present, ( new state ) and wrap it in a closure

Comment: It was down voted because its not DRY, dont repeat yourself, as well as from the standpoint of looking inside of handle_request() you have no way to know what the 'hidden' function is doing.  Generally just a bad practice thing.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Sorry don't get you - which object is being recreated? This is the defined way of passing function references in PHP. It may not necessarily be the best pattern to use in this specific scenario, but that wasn't the question... I would hope `handle_request` does more than just call redirect, but the OP adding that would not be **M**CVE

Comment: Thanks, this definitely answers the question; as you say, it isn't optimal vs the other option presented, but still helpful to know

Comment: @Rhumborl ~ edit the answer and i'll up vote it, my mistake I didn't realize the $app->( .. closure() ) part was a package deal ( from the OP's code ) if you know what I mean.  If you look at my comment under the OP I had looked at it like $obj was what was getting passed not $app

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix No problem, it is certainly still a fair point to make from a general design point of views

Comment: @Rhumborl - yes but I was a bit hasty sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the `$app object` and then call the `redirect` method from there.

#### Example

```
$app->get('/contact', function() use ($app) {
  $obj = new Obj;
  $obj->handle_request($app);
});

public function handle_request($app) {
  $app -> redirect('/about');
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for answering -- would there be a performance hit from passing around such a large object rather than a single property?

Comment: @cantera you are not passing objects around, but a reference to it.

Comment: As @ArtisiticPhoenix pointed out (and to be noted he also gave the same answer as I did), you are passing a reference to the object, not the actual object. So perfomance should not be affected :)

Comment: I would add you can type hint the methods input with the class name of the object passed in much like you had done with callable.  This way latter you will know what object ( class instance ) is needed, and prevent other inputs that do not have a redirect method from being used.  This is the best practice way of doing it.